# Barchart is connected to each other but I need it to be separate

Tags: java, jfreechart

Everything seems to be working fine, the only problem is that the chart is supposed to be produced is a bar chart that is not connected to each other, however the chart I ended up with is not the one I intended for.

I followed a video and the code seemed to be similar, so I can't figure out what went wrong:

```
try {
    int rubyPoints = Integer.parseInt(getHP("Ruby"));
    int amberPoints = Integer.parseInt(getHP("Amber"));
    int pearlPoints = Integer.parseInt(getHP("Pearl"));
    int sapphirePoints = Integer.parseInt(getHP("Sapphire"));
    DefaultCategoryDataset barChartData = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
    barChartData.setValue(rubyPoints, "House Points", "Ruby");
    barChartData.setValue(amberPoints, "House Points", "Amber");
    barChartData.setValue(pearlPoints, "House Points", "Pearl");
    barChartData.setValue(sapphirePoints, "House Points", "Sapphire");
    JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createAreaChart("House Points",
        "All houses", "Amount of points", barChartData, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);

    CategoryPlot barchrt = barChart.getCategoryPlot();
    barchrt.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.BLUE);
    ChartPanel barPanel = new ChartPanel(barChart);
    panelChart.removeAll();
    panelChart.add(barPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panelChart.validate();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    // error handling
}
```

The chart looks like this (which is not what I need it to look like):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple: the chart you've created is not a `barChart`, but an `areaChart`.

In order to get the result you want, just change the line where instantiating the chart to:

```
JFreeChart barChart = ChartFactory.createBarChart("House Points", 
    "All houses", "Amount of points", barChartData, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, false, true, false);
```

And you'll get something like:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, I can't believe it was such a simple mistake that I missed.